# How to fix FLS Create and FLS Update issue as per security scanner

Tags: apex, trigger, field-level-security, fls

[image]

[image]

String  attachmentLinks = '';

if(!commAttList.isEmpty()){
Database.insert(commAttList,false);

}
return attachmentLinks;

Comment: What is security scanner, and what are you trying to ask here? If you are facing a code review issue then try to solve it by yourself, google it etc, which will increase your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a managed package, or operating in a context where FLS and CRUD enforcement is required, which seems to be the case because you are using a static analyzer that enforces it, you must write code to validate the user's permission to perform DML operations and to access specific schema elements.

The approach to doing so in Apex is covered well in [this Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/secure-serverside-development/write-secure-apex-controllers?trail_id=security_developer), part of a longer trail that is well worth taking on building secure applications on the Salesforce platform.